# Speed up kendo ui datasource

Tags: asp.net, json, sql-server, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I Have a problem regarding a kendo ui grid and his datasource (kendo ui datasource loaded from another page on my local server).

firstly, i'm working on an intranet web application on an IIS server, using Classic ASP and a SQL server (version from 2008 to 2016)

this is my code:

```
     var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: [
        {
            template: '<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-refresh" href="\\#" onclick="clearFilter()"><span class="k-icon k-i-refresh"></span></a>'
        }
    ],
    selectable: "row",
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    height: 740,
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filterable: true,
    columnMenu: {
        columns: true,
        filterable: true
    },
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSize: 15,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    allowCopy: true,
    columns: [ 
        {
            field: "CRIT",
            title: "Criticità",
            // locked: true,
            lockable: false,
            groupable: false,
            width: 80,
            menu: true,
            filterable: {
                // ui: filtPerIdComb
            }
        }, 
        {
            field: "VIP",
            title: "Vip",
            lockable: true,
            width: 100,
            filterable: {
                // ui: filtPerRegion
            }
        }, 
        {
            field: "NOMETEC",
            title: "Tecnico/Ditta",
            lockable: true,
            width: 120,
            filterable:{
                // ui: filtPerProvince
            }
        },
        {
            field: "NOMEPC",
            title: "Nome Computer",
            // locked: true,
            lockable: false,
            groupable: false,
            filterable:{
                // ui: filtPerSiteName
            },
            width: 200
        },  
        {
            field: "COGNOME",
            title: "Cognome",
            lockable: true,
            groupable: false,
            width: 130,
            filterable:{
                // ui:filtPerCoordN
            }
        },  
        {
            field: "NOME",
            title: "Nome",
            lockable: true,
            groupable: false,
            width: 130,
            filterable:{
                // ui:filtPerCoordE
            }
        },  
        {
            field: "TEL",
            title: "Telefono",
            lockable: true,
            groupable: false,
            width: 80,
            filterable:{
                // ui:filtPerMasl
            }
        },  
        {
            field: "DIFETTO",
            title: "Difetto",
            lockable: true,
            width: 130,
            filterable:{
                // ui: filtPerCategory
            }
        },  
        {
            field: "DETTAGLI",
            title: "Dettagli",
            lockable:true,
            width: 130,
            filterable: {
                // ui: filtPerTipology
            }
        },  
        {
            field: "STATO",
            title: "Stato",
            lockable: true,
            width: 130,
            filterable:{
                // ui: filtPerContext
            }
        },  
        {
            field: "DATAAP",
            title: "Data Apertura",
            lockable: true,
            width: 150,
            filterable:{
                // ui: filtPerDescriptions
            }
        },  
        {
            field: "NPROG",
            title: "N° Progressivo",
            lockable: true,
            sortable: false,
            width: 150,
            filterable:{
                // ui: filtPerPlantRecords
            }
        }
    ],
    dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "servizivari.asp?funzione=provatabellakendo",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

My achieve is to get a table, containing all tickets that datasource load from the "servizivari.asp" page.

Now, the page "servizivari.asp" returns an application/json page, containing a json "hand-writed" (i don't use any library to make the recordset as a json string, i've wrote the code to do it and it works correctly. I know that while on sql 2016 i can use the "for json", but not where i have the previous version...)

this is the code of the "Servizivari.asp" page:

```
    response.clear
    response.ContentType="application/json"
    response.charset = "utf-8"
    set rst = libdb_getrs(conntemp, "select top 1000 t.colore as COLORE, t.tipologia as CRIT, i.vip as VIP, n.nom as NOMETEC, i.matricola as NOMEPC, i.cognome as COGNOME, i.nome as NOME, i.telefono as TEL, replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(i.desprob, char(13), ' '), char(10), ' '), char(39), '-'), char(34), '-'), char(47), '-'), char(92), '-'), ' ',char(17)+char(18)), char(18)+char(17), ''), char(17)+char(18), ' '), char(9), ' ') as DIFETTO, replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(i.risprob, char(13), ' '), char(10), ' '), char(39), '-'), char(34), '-'), char(47), '-'), char(92), '-'), ' ',char(17)+char(18)), char(18)+char(17), ''), char(17)+char(18), ' '), char(9), ' ') as DETTAGLI, i.stato as STATO, convert(date,i.dataap) as DATAAP, i.nprog as NPROG from inter i left join tipologie t on i.CDNAME = t.id left join nom n on n.id = i.nominativo")
    if not rst.eof then
        jsonarr = "["
        flag = true
        while not rst.eof
            colore = normalizzaperkendo(rst("COLORE"))
            crit = normalizzaperkendo(rst("CRIT"))
            vip = normalizzaperkendo(rst("VIP"))
            nometec = normalizzaperkendo(rst("NOMETEC"))
            nomepc = normalizzaperkendo(rst("NOMEPC"))
            cognome = normalizzaperkendo(rst("COGNOME"))
            nome = normalizzaperkendo(rst("NOME"))
            tel = normalizzaperkendo(rst("TEL"))
            difetto = normalizzaperkendo(rst("DIFETTO"))
            dettagli = normalizzaperkendo(rst("DETTAGLI"))
            stato = normalizzaperkendo(rst("STATO"))
            dataap = normalizzaperkendo(rst("DATAAP"))
            nprog = normalizzaperkendo(rst("NPROG"))
            if not flag then
                jsonarr = jsonarr &","
            END IF
            flag = false
            jsonarr = jsonarr &"{""COLORE"":"""&colore&""",""CRIT"":"""&crit&""",""VIP"":"""&vip&""",""NOMETEC"":"""&nometec&""",""NOMEPC"":"""&nomepc&""",""COGNOME"":"""&cognome&""",""NOME"":"""&nome&""",""TEL"":"""&tel&""",""DIFETTO"":"""&difetto&""",""DETTAGLI"":"""&dettagli&""",""STATO"":"""&stato&""",""DATAAP"":"""&dataap&""",""NPROG"":"""&nprog&"""}"
            rst.movenext
        wend
        jsonarr = jsonarr & "]"
    else
        jsonarr= "select top 1000 t.colore as COLORE, t.tipologia as CRIT, i.vip as VIP, n.nom as NOMETEC, i.matricola as NOMEPC, i.cognome as COGNOME, i.nome as NOME, i.telefono as TEL, replace(replace(i.desprob, char(13), ''), char(10), '') as DIFETTO, replace(replace(i.risprob, char(13), ''), char(10), '') as DETTAGLI, i.stato as STATO, convert(date,i.dataap) as DATAAP, i.nprog as NPROG from inter i left join tipologie t on i.CDNAME = t.id left join nom n on n.id = i.nominativo"
    end if
    response.write jsonarr
    response.end
```

Notice that this query is just a development one, it will be little different since user can choose more column than me and set statement to filter data

Now under here u can see an example of the json the scripts return (20 rows):

```
    [{"COLORE":"Green","CRIT":"Verde Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"2/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"3/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"4/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"5/2016"},{"COLORE":"Green","CRIT":"Verde Critico","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"6/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"7/2016"},{"COLORE":"Green","CRIT":"Verde Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"8/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"9/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Critico","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"10/2016"},{"COLORE":"Green","CRIT":"Verde Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"11/2016"},{"COLORE":"Green","CRIT":"Verde Critico","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"12/2016"},{"COLORE":"Green","CRIT":"Verde Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"13/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"14/2016"},{"COLORE":"Yellow","CRIT":"Giallo Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"15/2016"},{"COLORE":"Yellow","CRIT":"Giallo Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"16/2016"},{"COLORE":"Green","CRIT":"Verde Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"17/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Critico","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"18/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"19/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"20/2016"},{"COLORE":"Black","CRIT":"Bianco Ordinario","VIP":"","NOMETEC":"xxx yyy","NOMEPC":"pcnamexxx","COGNOME":"Doe","NOME":"John","TEL":"1234567890","DIFETTO":"problem zzz","DETTAGLI":"solution xyz","STATO":"chiusa","DATAAP":"19/09/2016","NPROG":"21/2016"}]
```

Everything since here works, but if i want all the data the db contains (at least 10.000 rows up to 100.000 rows) obviously the script goes on timeout (i can reach a maximum of 3000 rows in this way).

Now, the step i have to get is that everybody (from 5-6 user to 30 user) can make their own view on this table (pre-filtering the data they get from the db adding some statement on the query), but in case they need to get every rows the Db contains (it's quite common for their job - they can also choose to get more column than i set on the query) i want to make it work and do it 
as fast as possible.

asp recordset has the pagesize method, if possible now i'd like to make server (and db more than iis) elaborate everything so on client it work faster.

i know i'm not so clear, but thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have you looked into [Virtualization](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data)?